# How to Pan around the view port with/using mouse side buttons (Button 4,and 5) in blender 2.8?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, mouse, navigation

Is there a way to **pan and zoom with side buttons on the mouse** in blender 2.8 ?

I can't seem to get the "Button4 Mouse" and "Button5 Mouse" Keymapping working on the "pan view" option.

**Side buttons are working for other inputs like opening pie menus** for shading and modes.(**these two are my current key mappings for the two side buttons** i have on my mouse, but I think pan and zoom in the view port would be more useful as a side button input.)

Sorry I'm new to blender and I don't understand the key mappings yet.